# How to add scopes to Facebook login with Firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, facebook-login, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add scope and access more properties of the signed in user from Facebook. However, Firebase 3 sdk seems to not be clear on that.

```
provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
provider.addScope('public_profile, email, gender, user_birthday');
firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then((result) => {
      var token = result.credential.accessToken;
      var user = result.user; // doesn't have any extra information
});
```

Has anyone figured out how to access additional scope?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The additional scope data are currently not available via firebase user. You will need to get the returned access token from result.credential.accessToken and then call the facebook api to get that additional data.

Comment: Does this mean that the `add_scope` is a noop?

Comment: When you addScope, the returned OAuth access token will give you access to that scope specific data. When you query the facebook api with that access token, you will be able to retrieve that scope specific data. FYI, Firebase is working on returning additional idp data like they did in the previous version.

Comment: hey! I'm doing that actually, I'm unable to add `user_posts` scope while login. The auth token given by firebase API is rejected by facebook when i try to access `user_posts` via graph API. please suggest a solution

Comment: Facebook requires review of sensitive scopes. Check this page: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/review/what-is-login-review Otherwise, they won't show them to the user.