# Getting data from Facebook API React

Tags: reactjs, firebase, facebook, api

I don't know how to get data about the user from Facebook API.
I wrote something like this so far :

```
export const signInFacebook = () =>{
    return (dispatch, getState) => {
        var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
        provider.addScope('user_hometown');
        firebase.auth().languageCode = 'pl_PL';

        firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
            console.log(result)

        })
    }
}
```

and got the response:
[image]

Now I don't know how can I get this `user_hometown` info for example...

Comment: addScope adds permissions. Not which fields you want back

Comment: Ok. Can you tell me how can I get these fields, or give some maunal how to do that, because I can't find good information in the Internet :v..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All of the data retrieved from the user is found within the "results" response that is returned in the .then promise. Results is the entire object that was returned from successful login, aka the object that you console-logged.

To access the data you want, you need to look at the hierarchy/path of the results object. Then what you can do is store the data in a variable or constant in key-value pairs which you can retrieve and use in other areas of your code. Below I have provided some example values retrievable from your results. Is anything unclear?

```
export const signInFacebook = () =>{
return (dispatch, getState) => {
    var provider = new firebase.auth.FacebookAuthProvider();
    provider.addScope('user_hometown');
    firebase.auth().languageCode = 'pl_PL';

    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(function(result) {
        const userData = {
            name: result.user.displayName,
            email: result.user.email,
            image: result.user.photoURL,
            birthday: result.additionalUserInfo.profile.birthday
        };
        console.log(result);

    })
}
}
```

Comment: I understand all. I know how to find these basic informations in result object. But I don't know where I can find information which I added with addScope() function. For example this 'user_hometown', because I don't see it in additionalUserInfo object...

Comment: I believe this post is relevant to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39218093/how-to-add-scopes-to-facebook-login-with-firebase. It seems that the actual data you are looking for isn't accessible by Firebase API. Instead, you must use the access token that is returned from Facebook Login to query Facebook Graph API and retrieve the data you want.